# Honestly, what's the difference between public variable and public property accessor?

Tags: c#, properties, field

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between a field and a property in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)
>   [Should I use public properties and private fields or public fields for data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277572/should-i-use-public-properties-and-private-fields-or-public-fields-for-data)

What is the difference between:

```
public string varA;
```

and

```
public string varA { get; set; }
```

Comment: It's been answered before here: [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The public property accessor gives you more flexibility in the future.

If you want to add validation to setting the value, you simply write a non-default setter.  None of your other code would have to be modified.

There could also be reasons you'd want to replace the default getter with code.  That can be a real pain with a public variable.

Comment: who writes code that depends on whether a visible name is a variable or a property? That's the only reason I can think of that this would matter, otherwise you can just change it and recompile.

Comment: @moz: What if your public variable was in a seperate binary? Your application would be using the variable.. when you change it to a property the variable disappears and you now have two generated functions. You'd have to recompile every binary which referenced it.

Comment: @Rob: so the property benefit applies primarily to libraries shipped as binaries only? For in-house code, not so much?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, you can also use a property to make the value read-only or even set-only:

```
public int Item { get; private set; } // read-only outside the class. Can only be set privately.
```

I have also run into situations where I later decide I want to proxy an object, or add AOP, which basically requires properties.

Answer (score 1):

Public property accesses fields and internal class code through exposed getter and setter methods.  A public field acesses the field directly.

Using propertys offers the potential to provide a layer of abstraction and design (ability to make set accessor protected, private).

When a property is specified and no body present an underlying private field is created by the compiler that is used to store the value against.  Essentially:

```
private int item = 0;
public int Item {
get { return item; }
set {item = value; }
}
```

In general I tend to use properties for public exposed variables and fields for private.  I might consider using a field if that field was accessed many times and speed was a crucial design requirement.