# How to reference parent variable with a different type without casting?

Tags: c#, casting

I have this situation

```
public class Base
{
    public Basedef def;
}

public class A : Base
{
}

public class B : A
{
    public int GetBar()
    {
        return def.bar;
    }
}


public class BaseDef
{
}

public class ADef : BaseDef
{
    public int foo;
}

public class BDef : ADef
{
    public int bar;
}
```

As you an see, there is an error in method B:GetBar(), because def have no access to bar, but if you make...

```
public int GetBar()
{
    return (def as BDef).bar;
}
```

should work, but i want to avoid casting, how to get properties from definition using reference created in Base class without using casting?

Why avoid cast?, because is prone to runtime errors and is easier to introduce bugs, I want type-safe coding.

What I am trying to do

```
public class Factory
{
    public static Base<BaseDef> Create(BaseDef d)
    {
        if(d is BDef)
            return new B(); //Error, can not convert B to Base<BaseDef>
    }
}

public class Program
{
    B instance = Factory.Create(new BDef()); //Error, can not convert to Base<BaseDef> to B
}
```

I am looking for an elegant solution

bye!

Comment: I assume you wanted ADef to inherit from BaseDef, but you didn't write it so it makes no sense to cast a BaseDef to a BDef...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid cast? What you're trying to achieve is not possible without virtual method or property/reflection

Comment: I've edited your question assuming you mean this `ADef : BaseDef`. If not edit your question back

Comment: Sriram, yes I mean that, thanks for pointing out that

Comment: Sriram, updated question, added why i want to avoid casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an elegant, no-casting solution, the compiler needs to know that `def` is a `BDef` in `GetBar()`. This is a way to do that, that I think will work well for your situation:

```
public class Base<T> where T : BaseDef
{
    public T def { get; set; }
}

public class A<T> : Base<T> where T : ADef
{
    public int GetFoo()
    {
        return def.foo; // this works, too
    }
}

public class B : A<BDef>
{
    public int GetBar()
    {
        return def.bar;
    }
}
```

(By the way, you should use public properties, not public fields. See [Honestly, what's the difference between public variable and public property accessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542827/honestly-whats-the-difference-between-public-variable-and-public-property-acce?lq=1) for some reasons why.)

**Update:** your `Factory` method might look like one of these:

```
public static Base<T> Create<T>(T d) where T : BaseDef
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(BDef))
        return (Base<T>)(object)new B();
    else
        return null;
}
public static T Create<T, U>(U d) where T : Base<U> where U : BaseDef
{
    T result;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
        result = (T)(object)new B();
    else
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    result.def = d;
    return result;
}
public static T CreateAlternate<T, U>(U d) where T : Base<U>, new() where U : BaseDef
{
    return new T { def = d };
}
```

Used like:

```
void Main()
{
    Factory.Create(new BDef());
    Factory.Create<B, BDef>(new BDef());
    Factory.CreateAlternate<B, BDef>(new BDef());
}
```

I like the last one because there's no casting, as long as the [`new()` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) isn't an issue, or the first if concise calling code is very valuable (because the generic type can be inferred).

Comment: I thought about this, it is possible for A to get foo value using its def reference?

Comment: @JoeCabezas Yes, my solution supports this, because the compiler knows that `def` is an `ADef`.

Comment: this is giving me errors: Base<BaseDef> b = new A<ADef>(); (Cannot implicitly convert type `A<ADef>' to `Base<BaseDef>')

Comment: For the same reason that `Collection<object> c = new ObservableCollection<string>();` is invalid: It simply doesn't make sense. How are you trying to use this? You might benefit from a `Base`, which would be a base class of `Base<T>`. If you only needed `T` to be `in` or `out`, you can use [co/contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx) on a generic interface, but as-is you have a `get` and a `set`, so that won't work.

Comment: added in my question "what i am trying to do", check it out if you have time please

Comment: @JoeCabezas I've added some example `Factory` methods for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not type safe to do it with the cast because what you're trying to do is fundamentally not type safe.

You have a class A and a class B that are subclasses of Base, and Base has a reference to BaseDef. BaseDef could be ADef or BDef, you don't know which one, certainly not from anything that is told to B.

But you *can* provide B with the information it needs to know that its BaseDef reference is actually a BDef, if you use generics.

```
public class Base<T> where T : BaseDef
{
    public T def;
}

public class A<T> : Base<T> where T : ADef
{
}

public class B : A<BDef>
{
    public int GetBar()
    {
        return def.bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why avoid cast?, because is prone to runtime errors and is easier to introduce bugs, I want type-safe coding.

I don't understand why cast is error prone, If you don't know what will be the `RuntimeType` of the `def` I'll say your design is wrong.

In my opinion you should be knowing what will be the runtime type of it.

There are workarounds

**Workaround 1:**

```
public int GetBar()
{
    if (def is BDef)
        return ((BDef)def).bar;

    return 0;//some default value
}
```

**Workaround 2:**
Introduce a `enum` saying `who am I`.

```
public enum DefType
{
    BaseDef = 0,
    ADef =1,
    BDef =2
}

public class BaseDef
{
    public virtual DefType MyType
    {   
        get{ return  DefType.BaseDef; }
    }
}

public class ADef
{
    public override DefType MyType
    {   
        get{ return  DefType.ADef; }
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```
switch(def.MyType)
{
    case DefType.ADef:
    {
        (ADef).foo;//you know who is this here right?
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense to make Basedef  an abstact class and bar an abstract property on it?

Comment: no, because bar is a specific property of B, the idea is to use Def classes to create instances of A and B

Comment: also, A, should not have access to bar using its own def