# Confused about a bit of c# code

Tags: c#

I need someone to help me understanding this bit of c# code:

```
public Teacher[] Teachers { get; set; }
```

I can see this is an array but is it ok to use get, set here instead of :

```
public Teacher[] Teachers = new Teacher[4];
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean Is it ok to use fields instead of properties?

Comment: This is called auto-implemented properties. [read here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: We were asked to create an array of Teacher and I saw someone wrote it like properties and I paste this code into Visual Studio and it does not complain. SO I am confused about it.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142867/what-is-difference-between-property-and-variable-in-c-sharp) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542827/honestly-whats-the-difference-between-public-variable-and-public-property-acce) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Teacher[] Teachers { get; set; }
```

This creates a **property** called Teachers of type `Teacher[]`.

```
public Teacher[] Teachers = new Teacher[4];
```

This creates a **field** called Teachers of type `Teacher[]` and initializes it will a length of 4.

You can initialize a property in the classes constructor:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public Teacher[] Teachers { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
       Teachers = new Teacher[4];
    }
}
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0) about the difference between a property and a field.

Comment: I think it would be a bit more correct if you said that your first sample code line created _both_ a property and a (hidden) field.