# Reference variable from a different method, class, file

Tags: c#

I need to reference the value of a variable in a different method, class, and file than the one I am currently in. I am brand new to C# and still trying to get these concepts.

Basic structure I have:

```
namespace Planning
{
    public class Service
    {
        public bool AddRoute(l, m, n)
        { 
            bool variable = xyz;
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to access that variable from a completely different file. I have looked at several questions already posted here but not of them deal with the exact level I am trying to access or how to access the variable from a method with parameters that I cannot access at that time.

Comment: `variable` does not exist outside of `AddRoute`. Why not make `AddRoute` return it, then you can make a `Service` object and call `AddRoute` on it to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i will not confuse you even more.

The "variable in the other class" should be a property of that class. You need to make sure it is public, and then, you need the `AddRoute` method get an instance of that class with that property set. You could then access the property value using something like `otherClassInstance.xyz`.

If the above confuses you, I suggest starting at the beginning, learning about Object Oriented Programming before attempting any coding at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can this not be done with a public property?

```
public class Service
{
    public bool MyVariable { get; set; }
    public bool AddRoute(l, m, n)
    {
        MyVariable = xyz;
    }
}
```

Comment: @EmpereurAiman - it's similar in practice, but not quite the same. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277572/should-i-use-public-properties-and-private-fields-or-public-fields-for-data) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't, period.

What you *can* do is set a `public` member variable:

```
namespace Planning
{
    public class Service
    {
        public bool variable;

        public bool AddRoute(l, m, n)
        { 
            variable = xyz;
        }
    }
}
```

But public member variables are frowned-upon, with good reason.

Better yet, add a read-only property that returns the value of a private member variable:

```
namespace Planning
{
    public class Service
    {
        private bool variable;

        public bool Variable
        {
          get 
          {
            return variable;
          }
        }

        public bool AddRoute(l, m, n)
        { 
            variable = xyz;
        }
    }
}
```

Then from elsewhere:

```
Planning.Service myObj = new Planning.Service();
myObj.AddRoute(1,2,3);

if (myObj.Variable)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can set that variable as return parameter of your method:

```
namespace Planning
{
    public class Service
    {
        public bool AddRoute()
        { 
            bool variable = true;
            return variable;
        }
    }
}
```

Call from different class:

```
namespace Planning
{
    public class AnotherClass
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Service service = new Service();
            bool otherVariable = service.AddRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

Now value of your variable from AddRoute method is inside otherVariable in another class.