# How to resolve type converting issues

Tags: c#

```
namespace learning
{
    class Gradebook
    {
        public Gradebook()
        {
            grades = new List<float>();  
        }
        public void AddGrade(float grade)
        {
            grades.Add(grade);
        }
        public Gradestatistic compute_statistics()
        {
            Gradestatistic stats = new Gradestatistic();
            float sum = 0f;
            foreach (float grade in grades)
            {
                sum = sum + grade;

            }
            stats.average_grade = sum / grades.Count;
            return stats;
        }
        List<float> grades;


    }
}
```

I am using two custom classes Gradebook and Gradestatistic respectively , my object of class gradestatistic is **stats** , average_grade is the member of class gradestatistic, when i built this program it shows error on **stats.average_grade = sum / grades.Count;**  which is **can not implicitly convert type float to learning.gradestatistic** .
learning is my project name.
the code of gradestatistic class is

```
class Gradestatistic
    {

        public Gradestatistic highest_grade;
        public Gradestatistic lowestgrade;
        public Gradestatistic average_grade;
    }
```

my program.cs code is

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Gradebook book = new Gradebook();
            book.AddGrade(91);
            book.AddGrade(89.9f);
            Gradestatistic stats = book.compute_statistics();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is failing to compile because you are trying to assign a value of type `float` to a field of type `Gradestatistic`. C# is a type-safe language which means you can't assign one type to another unless there is a conversion defined from one to the other.

Looking at your code it seems your `Gradestatistic` should have `float` type of fields, not `Gradestatistic`. Changing them to float will solve the issue:

```
class Gradestatistic
{
    public float highest_grade;
    public float lowestgrade;
    public float average_grade;
}
```

Although this will solve your problem, exposing a class fields like that is considered a bad programming practice. You can read more on that in the below questions:

- [Is it bad practice to use public fields?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields)
- [Should I use public properties and private fields or public fields for data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277572/should-i-use-public-properties-and-private-fields-or-public-fields-for-data)

You should prefer [automatic properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) over public fields.

Comment: yeah the problem is solved , thanks for your time , and I'll surely operate your suggestion of using properties over public field :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the Gradestatistic class to:

```
class Gradestatistic
{
    public float highest_grade { get; set; }
    public float lowestgrade { get; set; }
    public float average_grade { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)