# what is use of creating property in separate class for each entilty?

Tags: c#-3.0

I am learning some good code practice that's why i was going through some code, some thing i could not understand in it. It has made property in a separate class for each entity like in userClass it has property

```
  #region public properties

    private int uid;
    public int userId
    {
        get { return uid; }
        set { uid = value; }
    }

    private string uName;
    public string userName
    {
        get { return uName; }
        set { uName = value; }
    }

    private string pwd;
    public string password
    {
        get { return pwd; }
    //    set { pwd = value; }
    }


    private string uAddress;
    public string userAddress
    { 
        get { return uAddress; }
        set { uAddress = value; }
    }


    private string fName;
    public string firstName
    {
        get { return fName; }
        set { fName = value; }
    }

    private string lName;
    public string lastName
    {
        get { return lName; }
        set { lName = value; }
    }

    private string uPhone;
    public string userPhone
    {
        get { return uPhone; }
        set { uPhone = value; }
    }

    private string uMobile;
    public string userMobile
    {
        get { return uMobile; }
        set { uMobile = value; }
    }

    private int secretQuestion;
    public int securityQuestion
    {
        get { return secretQuestion; }
        set { secretQuestion = value; }
    }

    private string userAnswer;
    public string answer
    {
        get { return userAnswer; }
        set { userAnswer = value; }
    }

    #endregion
```

and from the business logic class it uses the property instead of using directly any entity's attribute name, but i am confuse whats there need to make a property like this?

other then this it has got enums for database column name which has a clear reason behind this that if in near future we have to change the database table's fields name then we don't have to change through out the whole business logic class and we can make changes to enum directly, But what is there use of creating property like this please elaborate me on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-implemented getters and setters vs. public fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111461/auto-implemented-getters-and-setters-vs-public-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really asking why it uses properties instead of having public fields?

Fields are an implementation detail - they're how data is stored, which shouldn't be something the outside world cares about, at least for 99% of types. Properties are part of the contract that a type has in terms of its API - the *implementation* is up to the type. In other words, it's a matter of encapsulation. Properties can be expressed in interfaces, as abstract methods etc, precisely because they keep the contract and the implementation separate.

Additionally, properties make databinding, debugging and various other things simpler. I have an [article about why properties matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx), which you may find useful.

Having said all of this, those properties are implemented in a tedious way - and they don't obey .NET naming conventions. I would have written them as:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
// etc
```

Comment: you said those properties are implemented in tedious way, how?

Answer (score 1):

Properties can be defined on Interfaces, but member fields cannot. So if you needed to refactor this class to a class that implements an interface, you can put the properties on the interface (and then have other classes that implement them as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Some similar questions:

[Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180860/c-public-fields-versus-automatic-properties)

[Property vs public field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272521/propertywith-no-extra-processing-vs-public-field).

In additional to above: Actually you can easily decide public field or property by yourself. It is quite easier to understand that:

(1) `Name` is a property of class `Person`

(2) `Speed` is a property of class `Plane`

(3) `Empty` is a public field of class `String`. If you say `String` has a property named `Empty`, it's really weird. And `String` has a property `Length` is easy to understand.